# Why am I getting an Array of an Array with Doctrine 2 & Symfony 2 Data Transformer?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have setup a [Symfony 2 Data Transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) that will allow the user to enter a comma separated list of string and convert that to an ArrayCollection which Doctrine expects. Now the problem is in the `transform()` where it will convert an `ArrayCollection` to a comma separated string.

```
/**
 * Transform ArrayCollection of Tag's into Comma Separated string
 * 
 * @param ArrayCollection $tags
 * @return string
 */
public function transform($tags) {
    if ($tags == null) 
        return '';

    $tagNames = array();
    var_dump($tags);
    $tags->map(function($tag) use(&$tagNames) {
        $tagNames[] = $tag->getName();
    });
    return implode(', ', $tagNames);
}
```

`$tags` look like:

```
object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)#222 (1) {
  ["_elements":"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":private]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(JM\BlogBundle\Entity\Tag)#53 (3) {
        ["id":"JM\BlogBundle\Entity\Tag":private]=>
        int(1)
        ["name":"JM\BlogBundle\Entity\Tag":private]=>
        string(4) "blog"
        ["description":"JM\BlogBundle\Entity\Tag":private]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice its an array in an array. Why is that?

**UPDATE: data transformer code -> http://pastie.org/3004780**

Comment: The tags created in reverseTransform(), how do they know to which Post object they belong to? I have a similar implementation with tags. They get loaded properly as a comma-separated list, but when saving, they get saved without their "post_id".. How can you pass the "post id" all the way to this transformer??..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in your `reverseTransform()` method, you're searching for a single tag with this line:

```
$tag = $this->em->getRepository('JM\BlogBundle\Entity\Tag')->findBy(array('name' => $strTag));
```

However, `findBy()` will always return an ArrayCollection, even if only one result is found. Try using `findOneBy()`, which will simply return the result without the ArrayCollection wrapper.

Also, for some prior art, check out the [FPNTagBundle](https://github.com/FabienPennequin/FPNTagBundle) and [Taggable Doctrine Extension](https://github.com/FabienPennequin/DoctrineExtensions-Taggable). In particular, the [TagManager](https://github.com/FabienPennequin/DoctrineExtensions-Taggable/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Taggable/TagManager.php) might have some optimizations that you can implement in your own code.